# How to give different color to draghandle in RangeSlider

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui, slider

i've been trying to change the color of the "balls" of the rangeSlider component of Kendo. I only changed both ball-color but it's the same. I need diferent color for each one. I thought there's something I can do in the html code

```
<div id="rSlider">
   <input />
   <input />
</div>
```

generating some class in css to make each input diferent from the other, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have different css foreach "ball" you can achieve it using css:

```
    .k-draghandle:first-of-type
    {
      background-color:#234;

    }
    .k-draghandle:last-of-type
    {
      background-color:#e23;

    }
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/EvUHo

Comment: I solved using first-child and last-child in the same way you say there.